# Form the differential equation from the given cartesian equation:

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Form the differential equation from the given cartesian equation:
$$y=ax^3+bx^2$$

My Attempt:
Given,
$$y=ax^3+bx^2$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=3ax^2+2bx$$
Again differentiating both sides with respect to $x$
$$\dfrac {d^2 y}{dx^2}=6ax+2b$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=ax^3+bx^2\tag1$$
$$y'=3ax^2+2bx\tag2$$
$$y''=6ax+2b\tag3$$
From $(3)$, $~xy''=6ax^2+2bx=2y'-2bx\tag4$

From $(2)$, $$xy'=3ax^3+2bx^2=3y-bx^2$$
$$\implies xy'=3y+\dfrac{1}{2}(x^2y''-2xy')\qquad \text{by $~(4)$}$$
$$\implies x^2y''-4xy'+6y=0$$
This is the required differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Second and third equations form a pair of linear equations in two variables $a$ and $b$. Solve for them and plug in first equation.

Answer (score 2):

If $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are two linearly independent solution of an ODE, then it given by
$$\left|\begin{matrix} y'' & y_1'' & y_2 '' \\ y'& y_1' & y_2'\\ y& y_1 & y_2 \end{matrix} \right|=0$$ Inserting $y_1=x^2, y_2=x^3$, we get
$$\left|\begin{matrix} y'' & 2 & 6x \\ y' & 2x & 3x^2 \\ y & x^2 & x^3 \end{matrix}\right|=0$$
$$-x^4 y''+ 4x^3 y' -6x^2 y=0 \implies x^2 y''-4xy'+6y=0,$$
which is homogeneous Eulrt ODE.

Answer (score 0):

$$y(x)=ax^3+bx^2$$
Susbtitute $x=e^t$
$$y(t)=ae^{3t}+be^{2t}$$
It's the solution of a linear second order differential equation with constant coefficients. The polynomial is 
$$(R-3)(R-2)=0 \implies R^2-5R+6=0$$
We can deduce the equation $y=y(t)$:
$$y''-5y'+6y=0$$
Susbtitute back $x=e^t$ where $y=y(x)$
$$x(y'+xy'')-5xy'+6y=0$$
Finally
$$x^2y''-4xy'+6y=0$$